# Bootstrap carousel controls not working and going to the next slide takes too long

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

My carousel is having some issues. It's taking a lot of time to go to the next slide. When I do it with controls, no matter how much I click on the controls, they don't work. I followed everything in the Bootstrap document but it's not working.

Code

```
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="images/wonyoung.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="loading">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="images/seungyoun.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="loading">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="images/yuri.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="loading">
              </div>
            </div>

            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
              </button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code I used to get the carousel to work, pasting the whole `.html` file with bootstrap imports of CSS & JS. It should work locally if you copy/paste into a `.html` file and open it with a web browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <title>Bootstrap Carousel Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div
        id="carouselExampleIndicators"
        class="carousel slide"
        data-bs-ride="carousel"
      >
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
          <button
            type="button"
            data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
            data-bs-slide-to="0"
            class="active"
            aria-current="true"
            aria-label="Slide 1"
          ></button>
          <button
            type="button"
            data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
            data-bs-slide-to="1"
            aria-label="Slide 2"
          ></button>
          <button
            type="button"
            data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
            data-bs-slide-to="2"
            aria-label="Slide 3"
          ></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img
              src="https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/61DiwECVps74bWazF88Cy9/2cc9411d050b8ca50530cf97b3e51c96/Image_Cover.jpg?fit=fill&w=480&h=270"
              class="d-block w-100"
              alt="..."
            />
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img
              src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTBsbCAQtQimp5yI0Zx4vyR_FzPLUVzkdjDBN0N4_LAUo59inNQrSp6-Iz7qrfAXBENLGI&usqp=CAU"
              class="d-block w-100"
              alt="..."
            />
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img
              src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRabXZSwdR-7wsXfdtb2Xdy0Tl9o6l1D-UcQnyVN0WxQ9TmPE8SkEh0s9opAyZy-x5DnYY&usqp=CAU"
              class="d-block w-100"
              alt="..."
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button
          class="carousel-control-prev"
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
          data-bs-slide="prev"
        >
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button
          class="carousel-control-next"
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
          data-bs-slide="next"
        >
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This helped me realize that I was using the wrong docs... bootstrap 5.1 uses "data-bs-slide" while bootstrap 4.0 uses "data-slide".